# What's the best way to mark wallboard for electrical box openings?

Tags: receptacle

Putting up 3/4" x 8' x 4' Plywood wall covering with a receptacle behind.
What is the best way to mark it out for the cut?

Guess just to measure the horizontal and vertical in reference from the sides.

Then there's the receptacle cover plate that is larger than the box.

Any cool handyman tricks for this?

Like to cut it after securing the plywood sheet. I've cut two already and they are mis-aligned.

Comment: Note that, if the box is behind the plywood, you need box extenders to shield the wooden edges in the cutout.

Answer (score 4):

You have to measure really accurately with this. With drywall you might be able to go with a rough location and cut the edges while the board is held or lightly screwed into the wall, but that probably won't work with something as rigid as plywood.

The opening in the wallboard should be sized to the electrical box. Then the cover plate helps you hide any gaps. One handyman tip is that they sell extra-large cover plates to help hide sloppier cuts!

You can also buy tools designed to help mark these cuts:
[https://www.amazon.com/Calculated-Industries-8105-Drywall-Electrical/dp/B00YX8KZGO/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00YX8KZGO)
or
[https://www.amazon.com/HandyMark-Drywall-Marker-2-Pack-HM1002-BF/dp/B000V5MPZM/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000V5MPZM)

One last idea if your cuts are significantly off is to replace the electrical boxes. You can get old-work boxes that attach to the wallboard (rather than structure). Just trace the outline of the box onto the wallboard and cut. I like to use an oscillating saw for this.

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is right. There's no rocket science involved. Make accurate measurements, marks, and cuts, and you won't have problems. Some tips:

- Make all measurements from adjacent panels (not the floor or other nearby points), as that's where the new panel will be installed.
- Be sure your tape measure is parallel to the edge of the sheet when measuring. Dimensions change when taken at an angle.
- Allow 1/16" around all boxes from your exact measurements when marking.
- Measure to the near and far edges of each box from the same point. For example, if a previously installed sheet is on the left, measure from there to the left side of the box, and then to the right side. Same from the top or bottom. Do not measure to one side of the box, and then add the width of the box. This introduces error.
- If you're up to the mental task, mark and cut the back of the sheet. This requires reversal of horizontal measurements, but your marks and any slips made with the saw will be hidden. You can also make the cuts with a circular saw and overcut slightly to get full blade penetration.

Answer (score 0):

Try mocking up the location with stiff cardboard. I use an old box, taped to the floor, with the edge of the box up against the wall. Then mark and cut the space in that. Once that's done, place the real sheet in place and mark out the opening. Check one more time and then cut.